# Need help for icons (leads/ customers)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, sketch-app, icon, adobe-xd

I am designing an app/ web and have problems finding icons to represent:

1. Leads
2. Customers

Icons are more for internal use rather than customer-facing.

Anybody have experience or ideas please? Thank you!!!

Comment: Hi YannieLiz, welcome to GD.SE. I think for getting an answer more adjusted to your needs, you should contextualize it, at least letting know what the application is about. The stereotype of clients icon is two shaking hands or a person with a briefcase shaking their hands with another, nothing representative in a clothing sales app.

Comment: If it's for internal use only and space is limited, then just use abbrevs "LEAD" and "CUST". No need for fancy, colored, animated, globally-understood icons, right?

Comment: Use noun project to search for [lead](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=lead) and [customer](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=customer)?

Comment: @usr2564301 you mean globaly misunderstood ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this in outline for 'leads' and with a solid fill for 'customers', eg. potential vs existing client base.

[image]